# 'child-selector' is not a known element Angular 2

Tags: angular, express, angular2-template

I am trying to perform communication from child component to parent component on certain action. For this purpose, I am using `EventEmitter` and  `Output` Libraries. I will show you what I have done so far.

Here is my **child component** file `sports-list.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sportslist',
    templateUrl: './sportslist.component.html'
})

export class SportsListComponent {
    @Output()
    contentUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.contentUpdated.emit('complete');
    }
}
```

Here is my **parent component** file `top-navigation.component.ts`

```
import { SportsListComponent } from '../../sportslist/sportslist.component';

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-ui-top-navigation',
  templateUrl: './top-navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-navigation.component.css']
}) 


export class TopNavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    get_data(event) {
        console.log('event trigger');
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

My `top-navigation.component.html`

```
<app-sportslist (contentUpdated)="get_data($event)">

</app-sportslist>
```

This is all my code looks like, when I try build this code, I get below error on my screen -

> ERROR in Template parse errors: 'app-sportslist' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'app-sportslist' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-sportslist' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> [ERROR ->] "):
>   ng:///var/www/html/budgetbet/BudgetBetWebSite/src/app/shared/top-navigation/top-navigation.component.html@419:0

I am new to express and angular, not understanding what its asking me to fix, your advise could be of much help.

### **Shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { TopNavigationComponent } from './top-navigation/top-navigation.component'; 
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({   
    declarations: [
        TopNavigationComponent,
        SportsListComponent   
    ] 
}) 
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: Have you declared the `SportsListComponent` in the same module with `TopNavigationComponent` or import the module where `SportsListComponent` is declared ?

Answer (score 3):

Add the child component to the declarations in the module

```
declarations: [
    ...,
    SportsListComponent
],
```

Comment: Hi @Sachila, Thanks for your reply, the component is already added in sportslist.module.ts file. But even if I add it to module file of top-navigation, it throws below error -
"SportsListComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules".
I am updating my question with shared.modules.ts file as well.

Comment: did u restart the cli

Comment: If it is in another module, import that module

Comment: @DIGVJSS you shouldn't add it in to two module u can import the SharedModule to sportslist.module.ts

Comment: @hana_wujira shared.module is already imported in sportslist module.

Comment: then export the `SportsListComponent` from the SharedModule after declaring it that means add it to `export:[SportsListComponent]`

Comment: None of that worked for me.. I added a workaround. I am interacting between parent and child component using the DOM elements.Adding triggers on elements of another component html helps here.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me to understand the messy import of components in Angular  https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

As @Sachila said, you have to declare the child component in the parent component module.

If they are in different modules export the child module and import it into the parent module

If they're in the same module make sure you have declared both components. Maybe it's just typo in this example but it looks like the following line is missing in your Shared.module.ts

import { SportsListComponent } from ../../sportslist/sportslist.component';

But the basic structure is as follows:

```
//...imports

@NgModule({
  imports: [           
    //for modules
  ],
  providers: [   
    //for services
  ],
  declarations: [  
    //for components
  ],
  exports: [/*elements to be shared with other modules*/],
  entryComponents: [],
})

//...
```